# How to draw grid lines only inside area

Tags: d3.js

I need to draw axis grid lines only inside area`s in Area Chart, written in D3 (version 4) .
Have any solutions`s of this issue?

Comment: Use **negative** width and height for the axis tick length

Comment: No, I need to draw only inside filled area, on other side of the area, there must be no grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative width and height for the axis tick length
And then use a CSS style to stroke the grid.

```
  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickSize(-height)
              .tickFormat("")
      );
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
              .tickSize(-width)
              .tickFormat("")
      );
```

**Edit**

If it is inside the Area define a clipping path that equals the area and group the grid lines to this clipping path.

Using the example from https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2015/d3js-area-chart/

```js
var data = [
    { x: 0, y: 10, },
    { x: 1, y: 15, },
    { x: 2, y: 35, },
    { x: 3, y: 20, },
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 575 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; })])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y);

var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("svg#area")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("clipPath")
   .attr("id", "area-clip")
   .append("path")
   .attr("d", area(data)); 

var grid = svg.append("g")
              .attr("clip-path","url(#area-clip)");
    
grid.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis.tickSize(-height).tickFormat(""));
grid.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(yAxis.tickSize(-width).tickFormat(""));
```

```css
.area {fill:steelblue;}
.grid line {fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="area"></svg>
```

Comment: this only draw grid lines. But... I need to draw this gridlines only in intersection of area and grid lines

Comment: need something like clipping path or mask

Comment: what if there are more than one area in the chart? how to get intersection of these area`s?